# While using a session variable in a condition I receive InvalidCastException exception

Tags: vb.net, exception

```
If Not Session("DateArrival") Is Nothing Or Not Session("DateDepature") Is Nothing Then

            **If Session("DateArrival") < CType(dpEmbarkDate.SelectedDate, DateTime) Then**

                isArrivalEmbarkDateInvalid = True

                If Session("DateDeparture") < CType(dpEmbarkDate.SelectedDate, DateTime) Then

                    isDepartureEmbarkDateInvalid = True

                End If

            End If
```

The line in bold generates the exception and the message "operator < is not defined for type
dbnull and type date."

I have searched Stackoverflow and none of the solutions found have worked.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the issue is. You're assuming that your session variable contains a `DateTime` but it doesn't. It contains `DBNull.Value`, which is what ADO.NET uses to represent database nulls. Presumably you set that session variable from a `DataTable` or some other query result and didn't bother to check that you actually had a `DateTime` value. Perhaps you were assuming that you would get `Nothing` if there was no value but you don't. If you're still confused, update the question with the code that sets the session variable.

Comment: OT, your `If` blocks are bad. I'm not sure exactly how bad because I'm not sure whether you genuinely meant to not check the departure date if there is no arrival date. You should have one statement like this: `If Session("DateArrival") IsNot Nothing AndAlso CDate(Session("DateArrival")) < dpEmbarkDate.SelectedDate Then`. The second one should be similar but I'm not sure whether it should be nested or not because I'm not sure of your specific logic. Note that it's the session variable you should be casting, not the property that is already type `DateTime`.